# Convert Javascript callback which can be called multiple times into promise

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Is there a way to convert a Javascript call with callback which can be called multiple times into a promise?

Say,

```
scan(function(result) {
  // this is actually a Bluetooth device scan (Cordova), and 
  // will return something when a device is found.
  // So this can be called more than once.
});
```

And wrap that into a promise?

```
function scanP {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    scan(function (result) {
     resolve(result); // attempt to call repeatedly, but doesn't work.
    });
  });
}

scanP(function(result) {
   // check if this device is what we want.
})
.catch(function(err) {
  // handle error
});
```

I also need this pattern to subscribe to data from a Bluetooth device. Is promise not suitable for this task?

**EDIT:** I'm using Bluebird.

Comment: `attempt to call repeatedly` - a Promise can only be fulfilled once (be it a resolve or a reject) - once it is fulfilled, it's value can not change

Comment: No, a promise is singular, use an observable or an event emitter

Comment: A Promise can indeed only be resolved once but he is creating a new Promise every time scanP is called which in turn, can be resolved. If I've understood correctly, what you've written is almost there except you want `scanP().then(function(result) {})`... here's an example: http://jsbin.com/johagevofe/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise is resolved only once. If want to resolve it multiple times then you want something other than promise.

You may want custom events (in browser), Node's `EventEmitter` or `Stream` (inherits `EventEmitter`, has `.pipe`, optional buffering). If all you want is a callback chaining solution then it seems not hard to write your own.